# Language Selection via onClick

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

I have created a bootstrap navigation bar for my website. I have also added a dropdown for language selection

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropright" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="language"></div></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" >
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="language=1;"><div id="languageDe"></div></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="language=2;"><div id="languageEn"></div></a></div>
</li>
```

, in which the labels are fetched from a JSON file that contains the correct labels for `language`, `languageDe` and `languageEn`. I also added an `onClick="language=1;"` and `onClick="language=2;"` as an attribute for the hyperlinks. I would like to use `"language='de'"` and `"language='en'"` instead of the numbers but I was not sure about the proper syntax. Now, I want to use the variable `language` to load the appropriate JSON language files `de.json` or `en.json`. But it does not seem to work this way.

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        let language = 1; // initialize language as german
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                // get language selection labels and put them into the div tags
                document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = response.language;
                  document.getElementById("languageDe").innerHTML = response.languageDe;
                  document.getElementById("languageEn").innerHTML = response.languageEn;
            }
        };
        // select language
        if (language===1) {
            xhttp.open("GET", "./json/de.json", true);
        } else if (language === 2) {
            xhttp.open("GET", "./json/en.json", true);
        }

        xhttp.send();  
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading language only once on windows onload event. Onclick attribute in your case did nothing. You have to call the appropriate function.

If I understood you correctly, Ithink the code below should work in your case.

```js
 function changeLanguage(language){
        localStorage.setItem('lang', language);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                // get language selection labels and put them into the div tags
                document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = response.language;
                  document.getElementById("languageDe").innerHTML = response.languageDe;
                  document.getElementById("languageEn").innerHTML = response.languageEn;
            }
        };
        // select language
        if (language===1) {
            xhttp.open("GET", "./json/de.json", true);
        } else if (language === 2) {
            xhttp.open("GET", "./json/en.json", true);
        }

        xhttp.send();  
 }
 
 
 
 window.onload = function() {
       if(!localStorage.getItem('lang')) changeLanguage(1);
       else changeLanguage(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lang')));
    };
```

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropright" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="language"></div></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" >
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="changeLanguage(1)"><div id="languageDe"></div></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="changeLanguage(2)"><div id="languageEn"></div></a></div>
</li>
```

**UPDATE** I've modified the code to keep previous value in localStorage

Comment: plus one for your answer! I will try this method and accept it if I succeed.

Comment: Great! This method does really change the text! But the problem is that the language changes back to the default language when I click on other links on my homepage.

Comment: Am I assuming your link causes the page to reload? If yes you need to store your previous choice somewhere. (cookies or localstorage).

Comment: You made my day! Thank you a lot for your update! That solved my problem.